# For report access on server, how to create manual entry using SQL in 'Secdata' table for multiple users of Power BI report Server Database?

Tags: reporting-services, powerbi

For report access on the server, how to create a manual entry using SQL in  'Secdata' table for multiple users of Power BI Report Server Database?

Comment: hi, it is not clear what you are asking, can you outline your requirements a more

Comment: i want to give access to users on reports (Power bi report server), using sql queries.But i am facing issue while creating entry in 'SecData' table of 'NtSecDescPrimary' image column.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server Reporting Services has the exact same table with the exact same NtSecDescPrimary column, so I assume it works the same as Power BI.

For SSRS, I found that the trick is to:

- Shut down the report server service.
- Fill in the XmlDescription field of the SecData table.
- Change the NtSecDescState field from 0 to 1. This marks the NtSecDescPrimary and NtSecDescSecondary fields as dirty.
- Start the report server service.
- Wait for the NtSecDescState field to turn back to 0.

At this point, the report server has filled in the NtSecDescPrimary/Secondary fields for you (and the new security policy will work)! You don't need to build the binary strings yourself at all.